# When I plug in a USB microphone it also becomes the audio output (ie not working) Ubuntu20.04

Tags: usb, sound, pulseaudio, microphone

I have a problem that if I boot my Ubuntu 20.04 system without my usb microphone connected it is fine. However, as soon as it is plugged in it becomes both input and output. Selecting the correct output restores sound... but the situation returns with a reboot. Settings aren't permanent.

Audio is Starship/Matisse on a TUF B450M-PLUS Gaming Motherboard.

This problem does not occur with Debian or Manjaro distributions -however I prefer Ubuntu for it's Steam stability and utility.

Answer (score 2):

find the profilename, use

```
pacmd list-cards | grep 'active profile'
```

Add the following to /etc/pulse/default.pa:

```
set-card-profile <cardindex> <profilename>
```

test it:

```
pactl set-card-profile <cardindex> <profilename>
```

alternative : use [earcandy](https://launchpad.net/earcandy)

Answer (score 2):

I installed Pulse Audio Volume Control and the problem went away.It would seem Gnome settings is somewhat buggy still.

Comment: Thank you @chester-hackenbush